# How to understand the batch size in CNN?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, theano, deep-learning

When using Theano with conv3d2d.conv3d, I found the input condition of signal is

```
signals_shape=(batch_size, n_frame, n_in_maps, height, width)
```

I think I do understand what does the batch size mean, which is the update frequency, but why would the batch size here being a dimension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `batch_size` is the number of examples you are going to use for this minibatch. For example, if your `batch_size` is 50, that means that you are training/testing 50 examples at a time. Consider if you had a 2d matrix to contain your data. It would look like an excel spreadsheet where each row is a separate example and each column is a `feature` of that example. The same thing is happening here, just in a higher dimension.

Comment: Why I think n_in_maps here stands for what you mean by the batch_size?

Comment: I suspect `n_in_maps` refers to the number of convolutional feature maps. Each convolutional layer will contain a certain number of feature maps, usually a few dozen depending on how complex the problem is. See here: http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/lenet.html#details-and-notation. Each layer has multiple `feature maps`.